# Filter as Numeric in Short text column in MSAccess file

Tags: ms-access, filter

I want to filter in MSAccess file in a column which is Short-Text type but i want to filter it as number: sample query is like as below--

> SELECT  node_no,d_card,t_card,card_no FROM data_card  where node_no=1
>   and convert(int,t_card)>=121432 ;

Comment: What happens when you run this query - error message, wrong result, nothing? As far as I know convert() is not Access intrinsic function. Post code for this UDF.

Comment: Access doest not support it, i need the alternative of this convert() part.

Comment: Try `Int([t_card])`.

Comment: Great! working thanks